# Calculate and store function outputs in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, for-loop, printing

I have a code like this:

```
nList = [[[0,0,0],[100420,0,623400]],\
[[]],\
[[100043,1324000,123240]],\
[[0,0,543],[3002340,443000,34300],[334000,4043400,7342],[0,0,134020]]
import math
prevX, prevY, prevT = 0, 0, 0

#Entry point
for traceIndex in range(0, len(nList)):
    print 'trace: ' + str(traceIndex+1)
    trace = nList[traceIndex]
    for pointIndex in range(0, len(trace)):
        point = trace[pointIndex]
        if len(point)>0:
            tempX, tempY, tempT = point[0], point[1], point[2]
            if pointIndex != 0:
           #calculate time difference here
                timeDiff = calculateTime (tempT,prevT)
```

Basically, `nList` has sublists before each `\` called traces and each trace has points of three elements. E.g., `nList[0][0]` produces trace 1, point 1= `[0,0,0]`. `point=[x-coordinate, y-coordinate, time]`. I have calculated timeDiff of each point in each trace. Now I need to sum up the timeDiff of the different traces and print them so that:

```
trace: 1
623400
trace: 2
trace: 3
trace: 4
187393
```

nList is made of sublists called 'trace' with each 'trace' having one or more points with 3 elements, [x, y, t]. for example, trace1 has 2 points such that trace1point1 = [0,0,0] and trace1point2=[100420,0,623400]. timeDiff calculates the difference between t2 and t1. for trace1, this would be (623400-0). trace4, compared to trace 1 has many more points and timeDiff would be for individual trace4pointN with `1=<N=<4`, (34300-543),(7342-34300) and (134020-7342). I want to write a program that takes all the timeDiffs in each trace and sums them up in a manner as to produce output mentioned above.

Comment: What is `timeDiff`? You say that you want to "sum up the timeDiff of the different traces". Which `timeDiff`s do you want to sum? Is there more than one? What is the "trace4 output"? What does it mean for it to "essentially" be something? What is a "3-coordinate point in trace"? What is an "individual difference in third element"?

Comment: nList is made of sublists called 'trace' with each 'trace' having one or more points with 3 elements, [x, y, t]. for example, trace1 has 2 points such that trace1point1 =  [0,0,0] and trace1point2=[100420,0,623400]. timeDiff calculates the difference between t2 and t1. for trace1, this would be (623400-0). trace4, compared to trace 1 has many more points and timeDiff would be for individual trace4pointN with 1=<N=<4, (34300-543),(7342-34300) and (134020-7342). I want to write a program that takes all the timeDiffs in each trace and sums them up in a manner as to produce output mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   nList = [[[0,0,0],[100420,0,623400]],\
         [[]],\
         [[100043,1324000,123240]],\
         [[0,0,543],[3002340,443000,34300],[334000,4043400,7342],[0,0,134020]]]
    for trace in nList:
        list1=list()
        trace_index = nList.index(trace)
        print "trace%d"%(trace_index+1)
        if len(trace)>1:
            for point in trace:
                list1.append(point[2])

            list2 = list1[1:]
            list1.pop()
            output = (abs(i2 - i1) for i2,i1 in zip(list2,list1))
            print(sum(output))
```

This should work. Basically I formed a list by extracting the times in each point of a trace. Then formed a duplicate list of the same. Removed the first element from one list and last from the other. Then subtracted the lists. Adding the elements in the resulting list gives the output.

Comment: Well i was unaware of torkil posting the answer. You may go with his answer. It uses the same logic but looks more concise and neat.

Answer (score 2):

This is easier solvable using zip and iterating directly over the elements to avoid the need for as much storing in variables. Based on your example output you want the absolute difference between each timepoint:

```
traces = [[[0,0,0],[100420,0,623400]],\
[[]],\
[[100043,1324000,123240]],\
[[0,0,543],[3002340,443000,34300],[334000,4043400,7342],[0,0,134020]]]
TIME_INDEX = 2  
traceCounter = 1
for trace in traces:
    print "trace:", traceCounter
    traceCounter += 1

    if len(trace[0]) < 2:
       #no coordinate in first element of trace, nothing to do
       continue

    #Zip takes several lists as arguments and returns list of lists with every 0th element in the 0th list, every 1st element in the 1st list etc. 
    timeStamps = zip(*trace)[TIME_INDEX]


    sumOfTimeDiffs = sum([abs(y-x) for x, y in zip(timeStamps[:-1], timeStamps[1:])] )

    if sumOfTimeDiffs > 0:
       print sumOfTimeDiffs
```

Output:

```
trace: 1
623400
trace: 2
trace: 3
trace: 4
187393
```